# _REQUIREDNAME always nil

Tags: lua, package

I'm trying to use the method for naming a lua package after the filename mentioned [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/15.3.html), however `_REQUIREDNAME` is never defined. For example I have these two files

samplePackage.lua:

```
print("_REQUIREDNAME: ", _REQUIREDNAME)
return nil;
```

packageTest.lua:

```
require "samplePackage"
```

And when I run packageTest.lua it outputs `> _REQUIREDNAME:   nil`

I also couldn't find any mention of _REQUIREDNAME in the Lua 5.1 Refrence manual, so was this removed from the language, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way that packages and modules work underwent some major changes in Lua 5.1, making the first edition of Programming in Lua mostly obsolete regarding that subject.

In 5.1, the module name is passed as an argument to the module by `require`. You can access it with `...`:

```
print("Module name: ", ...)
```

The [second edition](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/pil2/) of Programming in Lua covers Lua 5.1. It isn't free, but the chapter about packages and modules is [available as a sample (PDF)](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/pil2/chapter15.pdf).